# Correct approach for a user profile dynamic route in NextJS?

Tags: next.js

I have a dynamic route that displays a user profile. I want to show a "user does not exist" message if the URL slug they've entered does not map to a valid user, and I know that the next.js docs suggest to use `getStaticPaths` for this kind of scenario, but my understanding is that these paths are generated when the app is built. I am not sure if this approach will be best in the case of user profiles because it means that the app will need to be rebuilt every time a user subscribes. Is that correct?

Right now I am using `getServerSideProps` to grab the dynamic route query and perform a database lookup to see if the user exists. If so, render the profile page, and if not render the error instead. Is there any problem doing it this way?

Comment: There are some suggestions in the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication

Comment: There's no problem in doing it that way if you want the authentication to occur server-side. Another option would be having the authentication done on the client-side instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

> You should use `getStaticPaths` if you’re **statically** pre-rendering
> pages that use dynamic routes.

Your user pages will not be static if users are able to sign up. Since you won't be able to generate static paths after the build you cannot use getStaticProps in the dynamic page.